# How to get div without class with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I try to get 'Galatasaray.' from following HTML. I don't know how can I specified that

```
<div class="dRib1">
    <h2>Bilgi</h2>
</div>

<div>Galatasaray.</div>
```

Comment: Did you read the Html Agility Pack docs?

Comment: I solved my problem and shared the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlNodeCollection aciklamaCek = dokuman.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dRib1']");

textBox8.Text = aciklamaCek[0].NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText.Trim();
```

I solved my problem with this code.

Comment: I'm not sure that `.NextSibling.NextSibling` points to right element.

Comment: I couldn't find any answer for my problem on web. Firstly i thought it was absurd too but it works fine. I got about 60K data with this code then i share the solution maybe it will be helpful to someone.